# How to set a new property and provide its setter in Groovy

Tags: groovy, closures, metaprogramming

I have this groovy class:

```
class Car {
    int speed = 0
}
```

I want to use metaprogramming to introduce a new property "color" and also provide setColor method to an instance of the **Car** object, like this:

```
 def c = new Car()

 c.metaClass.setProperty("color", "red")

 c.metaClass.setColor = { 
       def newColor-> "color switched from $existingColor to $newColor
 }
```

My ultimate goal is that when I call:

```
c.color("yellow")
```

it prints out:

```
color switched from red to yellow"
```

I have gotten the **c.color** part working with my above code, but not the second part (setColor).

Could someone help me accomplish this or tell me if it is  even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a property, you get both the getter and setter for free, e.g.

```
class Car {
    int speed = 0
}
def c = new Car()
c.metaClass.setProperty("color", "red")
assert c.color == 'red'
c.setColor('blue')
assert c.getColor() == 'blue'
```

If the ultimate goal is to invoke a method called `color` to set the `color` property, you can add one like this:

```
c.metaClass.color << { col ->
    println "color switched from $delegate.color to $col"
    c.color = col
}

c.color('yellow') // prints "color switched from blue to yellow"
assert c.color == 'yellow'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are so very close to getting it working. Since you made a new property that has a setter, all you have to do is this:

```
 c.metaClass.getColor = {'red'}

 c.metaClass.setColor = { 
       def newColor-> println "color switched from ${delegate.color} to $newColor"
 }

 c.color = "yellow"
```

Please note, that this does not make a property that is set, but merely provides a mechanism to inject a get and a set method for the delegates color.

it could probably be fixed by doing this:

```
def currentColor = 'red'
def previousColor = '' 
c.metaClass.getColor = { currentColor }
c.metaClass.getPreviousColor = { previousColor }

c.metaClass.setColor = { 
   def newColor-> previousColor = delegate.color; currentColor = newColor
}
c.color = "yellow"
println "Changed color from $c.previousColor to $c.color"
c.color = "blue"
println "Changed color from $c.previousColor to $c.color"
```

but now we're into code that is purely for experiments not for production :)